# I put an "else {return false}" in a function with for loop and now it won't work.(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a log in function, so that when I input the username and password that is in the database, it will check to see if this matches and return a newsfeed. The database is like this:

```
var database=[
    {
        username:"Jay",
        password:"1234",
    },
    {
        username:"Kate",
        password:"4567",
    },
    {
        username:"Betty",
        password:"789",
    }

]
var newsfeed=[
    {
        username:"Jay",
        timeline:"happy"
    },
    {
        username:"Kate",
        timeline:"sad"
    },
    {
        username:"Mary",
        timeline:"boring"
    },
    {
        username:"Betty",
        timeline:"peaceful",
    }

];
```

Now I try to get the prompt in the username and password, such as "Betty" and "789", it returns "sorry, wrong username and password" but it is in the database!! Here is the code:

```
var usernamePrompt = prompt("what is your username");
var passwordPrompt = prompt("what is your password?");

function isUserValid(username, password) {
    for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
        if (database[i].username === username &&
            database[i].password === password) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
        function signIn(username, password){
        if (isUserValid(username, password)){
            console.log(newsfeed);
        }else{
            alert("sorry, wrong username and password");
        }
    }
    signIn(usernamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

I just get the correct answer that is as below, but 1) I do not understand the difference between putting an "else" and not putting it. 2) I do not understand why we do not need to put "if (isUserValid(username, password===true))" to indicate the condition needs to be matched.

```
var usernamePrompt = prompt("what is your username");
var passwordPrompt = prompt("what is your password?");

function isUserValid(username, password){
    for(var i=0;i<database.length;i++){
        if(database[i].username===username&&           
            database[i].password===password){
               return true;
            }
                }
            return false;
        }

function signIn(username, password){
        if (isUserValid(username, password)){
            console.log(newsfeed);
        }else{
            alert("sorry, wrong username and password");
        }
    }
    signIn(usernamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

Thank you for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code it will return as soon as the first object is iterated.Use `some` which will check if any object is matching the value that is supplied through the prompt. If any value matches then it will return true.Also use `toLowerCase` to make a case insensitive search

```js
var database = [{
    username: "Jay",
    password: "1234"
  },
  {
    username: "Kate",
    password: "4567"
  },
  {
    username: "Betty",
    password: "789"
  }

];
var newsfeed = [{
    username: "Jay",
    timeline: "happy"
  },
  {
    username: "Kate",
    timeline: "sad"
  },
  {
    username: "Mary",
    timeline: "boring"
  },
  {
    username: "Betty",
    timeline: "peaceful",
  }

];

function isUserValid(username, password) {
  return database.some(item => item.username.toLowerCase() === username.toLowerCase() && item.password.toLowerCase() === password.toLowerCase());
}


function signIn(username, password) {
  if (isUserValid(username, password)) {
    console.log(newsfeed);
  } else {
    alert("sorry, wrong username and password");
  }
}

var usernamePrompt = prompt("what is your username");
var passwordPrompt = prompt("what is your password?");


signIn(usernamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The else is returning false after the first element only .it should check for all the elements and then return false .

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify using `.some` function.

```js
database = [
  { username: "user1", password: "pass1" },
  { username: "user2", password: "pass2" },
  { username: "user3", password: "pass3" },
];
const isUserValid = (username, password) =>
  database.some(
    ({ username: du, password: dp }) => du == username && dp == password
  );
function signIn(username, password) {
  if (isUserValid(username, password)) {
    return "AUTHORIZED";
  } else {
    return "sorry, wrong username and password";
  }
}

console.log(signIn("user", "pass"));
console.log(signIn("user2", "pass2"));
console.log(signIn("user1", "pass"));
```

Answer (score -1):

It fails because if the username/password is not the very first one in the database then it won't match, returns `false` and exits the function. The for-loop does not continue looking for other matches. You only want to return `false` if you've checked all of the possibilities.

Separate your functions more clearly so they're easier to understand like this:

```
const usernamePrompt = prompt("what is your username");
const passwordPrompt = prompt("what is your password?");

function isUserValid(username, password) {
  for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
    if (database[i].username === username) {
      // found the user. return true if the password is right, otherwise false
      return database[i].password === password;
    }
  }
  return false; // <-- false if user is never recognized
}

function signIn(username, password) {
  if (isUserValid(username, password)) {
    console.log(newsfeed);
  } else {
    alert("sorry, wrong username and password");
  }
}

signIn(usernamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

Comment: it will break loop even in false...
`return database[i].password === password;` and return from function

Comment: Is this expression ```if (isUserValid(username, password))``` already indicates that, only if everything in the function returns positive result, then whatever comes next will run? Thank you.

Comment: it will only break the loop with false if the username matches. I'm not sure why the downvote - this logic is sound.

Comment: @Ellie the expression `if (isUserValid(u,p))` is like saying `const ok=`isUserValid(u,p); if (ok) {...}`. We're calling the isUserValid function and doing something depending on the answer. If the name/pw does not match we'll get `false` returned and show an error.